# ¿Como devolver a AJAX el valor una función SOAP?

Tags: php, ajax, soap

Tengo este servidor SOAP:

```
    //nusoap gehitu
require_once('../NUSOAP/lib/nusoap.php');
require_once('../NUSOAP/lib/class.wsdlcache.php');

//zerbitzaria sortu
$server = new soap_server;

//funtzioa inplementatu
function passEg($pass){
    $aurk = false;
    $lineas = file("../DATUAK/toppasswords1.txt");

    foreach($lineas as $linea){
        if (strstr($linea,$pass)){
            $aurk = true;
        }
    }
    return $aurk;
}

$server->register("passEg");

//service metodoari deitu
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Y tengo este cliente que usa ese servidor:

```
require_once('../NUSOAP/lib/nusoap.php');
require_once('../NUSOAP/lib/class.wsdlcache.php');

//bezeroa sortu eta zerbitzaria atzitu
$soapclient = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/lab7/PHP/egiaztatuPasahitza.php?wsdl',false);

//funtzioari deitu
if (isset($_POST['pasahitza'])){
    $pasahitza = $_POST['pasahitza'];
    echo $soapclient->call('passEg',array("pass"=>$pasahitza));
}
```

Esta es la función que llama a AJAX:

```
        function egiaztatuPasahitza(){
        var frm = $("#galderenF");
        var data=frm.serialize();
        var request = $.ajax({
            url:'passEg.php',
            method: frm.prop('method'),
            data: data,
            dataType:'html'
        });
        request.done(function(data){
            alert(data);
            if(data == true) {
                alert("Pasahitza hori ezin duzu sartu.");
             } else {
               alert("Pasahitza hori sar dezakezu.");
            }
        });
        request.fail(function(data){
            alert("Errorea");
        });
    }
```

Lo que pasa es que me da el siguiente error y no recoge bien el resultado:

> Array to string conversion in **C:\xaaamp\htdocs\lab7\PHP\passEg.php** on line **12**
>   Array

En varios ejemplos que he visto no tienen la necesidad de convertir a string el valor y no sé la razón de ese error.
Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**El aviso** que estás recibiendo es por querer tratar como un String a un Array:

> Array to string conversion in **`[archivo]`** on line **`[número]`**

Y luego, estás recibiendo lo que PHP imprime cuando intenta imprimir un Array:

> ```
> Array
> ```

Por ejemplo, podríamos reproducirlo con:

```
$ejemplo = array(1,2,3,4);
echo $ejemplo;
```

---

**En tu código**, sucede lo mismo con el resultado obtenido del webservice con `SoapClient->call();` (que es un array) en la línea:

```
echo $soapclient->call('passEg',array("pass"=>$pasahitza));
```

Una forma en que podrías solucionarlo, imprimiendo el contenido de la variable para depurarlo, es:

```
$resultado = $soapclient->call('passEg',array("pass"=>$pasahitza));
var_export($resultado);
```

Y luego, una vez que tengas claro cómo es la estructura del dato recibido del webservice, quizás lo quieras pasar como JSON al cliente, o como te interese manipular ese dato.